# Почему окну при создании не присваивается размер?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Есть класс

```
  import javax.swing.*;
  import java.awt.*;

  public class GraphicsWindow extends JDialog {
  public GraphicsWindow create(){

    setVisible(true);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 900));

    add(new GraphicsPanel());

    return this;
}

}
```

В нем я хочу создать диалоговое окно с заранее нарисованной панелью `GraphicsPanel` (это тоже мой класс, который к этому вопросу отношения не имеет).

В методе `actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)` я обрабатываю событие нажатия на кнопку

```
if (e.getSource() == graphicsButton){
GraphicsWindow graphicDialog = new GraphicsWindow().create();
graphicDialog.setVisible(true);
}
```

Которое должно создавать окно размером `900 на 900`, как я указал в методе `create()` Однако почему-то окну не присваивается никакой размер и вот что выходит в итоге:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так происходит? Как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте минимальное значение величины окна.

```
    Dimension dim = new Dimension( 900, 900);
    setPreferredSize( dim );
    setMinimumSize(  dim );
```

Поскольку окно содержит панель в которой тоже не указаны минимальные размеры и она пустая, окно сжимается.